# Many sites, same IP address, all linked together

Tags: seo, google-search, ip-address

Our client will have 5 domains on the same IP address. he uses Shopware (e-commerce platform). He wants to migrate his shops to a single shop with sub shops. So he can access them all from single /backend/admin/.

So:

- There are 5 shops (sub shop) in 5 domains.
- Some of sub shops have similar content.
- They have links, linking one to another.
- Each sub shop is a separate company in the real world

Does google knows or even wants to know these are different companies and does it affect ranking anyhow?

Comment: Are these "separate" shops selling "related" products?

Comment: Yes, some of them are related, some are absolutely same.

Comment: What's the reason for _duplicating_ the "same shop"? The fact that these shops are on the "same IP address" is irrelevant.

Comment: I dont know that. That is customer's request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these the same items? If they are the same items, then you'll need to make sure the text and photo content on the pages are very different or you may get hit by a panda duplicate content penalty.

Google will see these as separate domains, just link up to a google search console with each one. If the content on each page is different and the domain is different you should be good. The moment you start reusing text though, or reusing images, you'll likely put yourself into hot water. I'd also keep the interlinking between the domains to a minimum. Like you can link to sister sites, but if you mess around with outbound links too much you might get yourself penguined or phantomed.

Comment: "a panda duplicate content penalty" - I'm not aware of an actual "penalty" as such? It's simply "duplicate content". The pages will naturally compete against each other for ranking. If they are perceived to be "duplicate" then only one is likely to rank - which may not be the one you would hope. Unless you take additional steps to canonicalise the shops - but that doesn't seem to be the intention here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Panda Wikipedia and Moz on the google panda penalty. https://moz.com/learn/seo/google-panda It's both an algorithmic penalty and a manual one. The sites also will compete against each other and both lose out on traffic.